# How can I change the connection timeout setting in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, timeout

When I load a page which can't be connected for some reasons, before Firefox shows the error **"The connection has timed out"**, I will wait for about three minutes. I want change the Firefox connection timeout value to 20 seconds. I found something here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342310/where-can-i-find-the-default-timeout-settings-for-all-browsers, but it doesn't mention how to set the connection timeout value, please help!

Answer (score 29):

You can change the timeout settings by typing "about:config" in the address bar and then filtering on "timeout":

```
network.http.connection-timeout
```

Answer (score 15):

After the last Firefox update we had the same session timeout issue & following setting helped to resolve it.

We can control it with network.http.response.timeout parameter.

1. Open Firefox & type in ‘about:config’ in the address bar & press Enter.
2. Click on the 'I'll be careful, I promise' button.
3. Type ‘timeout’ in the search box and network.http.response.timeout parameter will be displayed.
4. Doube click on the ‘network.http.response.timeout’ parameter & enter the time value (it is in seconds) that you dont want your session not to timeout, in the box.

Answer (score 8):

While this used to be possible with network.http.connection-timeout, this ceased to be used in 2001.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.connect.timeout

Comment: network.http.connection-timeout actually appears to work as of 2019 in Firefox 68